# I am designing a programming that calculates the odds of profiting if you played several scratch- off lottery games

Tags: c++, file-io

This is the code I have written so far to calculate the odds of profiting from playing lottery scratchers. I have to prompt the user for out output file name (output.txt), where a formatted table with the results will be written. So far my program will output the results, but not in an output file. I am not really sure how to do that or where that will go in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
  {
    // Declaring variables
 int lowestAmountOfProfit;
 char filename[]="scratcher.txt";
 string gameName;
 int CostOfTicket, NumberOfPrizes;
 int PrizeValue, NumberOfTickets, TicketsNotClaimed;
 double RemainingTickets;
 double RemainingTicketsForProfit;
 double odds;

// The program will ask the user to enter the lowest amount they would like to
// profit when playing the lottery.

cout << "Enter the lowest dollar amount that you would like to profit: "
cin >> lowestAmountOfProfit;
cout << "Enter the output file name: "
cout << "Generating report..."

//open input file
ifstream fin;
fin.open(filename);

//if input file does not exist
if (!fin)
{
    // If the input file cannot be found.
    cout << "Input file does not exist." << endl;
    return 0;
}

//How the output displace will be formatted.
cout << left << setw(25) << "Game" << setw(10) << "Cost" << setw (10) << "Odds" << endl;
cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;

// Reads the name of the game
while (getline(fin, gameName))
{
    fin >> CostOfTicket; // Reads the cost of ticket
    fin >> NumberOfPrizes;  // Reads the number of prizes
    RemainingTickets = 0;
    RemainingTicketsForProfit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfPrizes; i++)
    {
        fin >> PrizeValue; // Reads the prize value
        fin >> NumberOfTickets; // Reads the total number of tickets
        fin >> TicketsNotClaimed;   // Reads number tickets not claimed


    //regardless of prize value*/
        // The following line computes the running sum of the number of tickets remaining for that game.
        RemainingTicketsForProfit = RemainingTicketsForProfit + TicketsNotClaimed;

        // The next line with compute a sum of the number of remaining tickets where the user would profit.
        if (PrizeValue > lowestAmountOfProfit)
        {
            RemainingTickets = RemainingTickets + TicketsNotClaimed;
        }

    }

    // Tells program what to do if there are zero remaining tickets
    if (RemainingTickets==0)
    {
        // Formats the output
        cout << left << setw(25) << gameName << setw (2) << "$" << CostOfTicket << right << setw(15) << "Not possible"  << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        // Tells the program to calculate the odds
        odds = RemainingTicketsForProfit / RemainingTickets;
        cout << left << setw(25) << gameName << setw (2) << "$" << CostOfTicket << right << setw(15) << "1 in " << setprecision(2) << fixed << odds << endl;
    }
    // Read the blank line
    string blankLine;
    fin >> blankLine;
}

// Close the input file
fin.close();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output to a file by just declaring it as a `ofstream` and then basically using it as a `cout`.  Like so:

```
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("filename.txt");
cout << "Enter the first number: ";
cin >> num1;
outputFile << num1 << endl;
outputFile.close();
```